# Let .htacces block subdomain except if came from other certain subdomain (for wp-admin security wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite, block

I came op with an idea to improve my Wordpress security.

The loginpage is always /wp-admin. So that's easy for hackers. I know you can block al the calls to /wp-admin except from your own IP adress. But that's often not a solution because you want to be able to upload posts etc. from everewhere, not just home.

Is it not a solution to block /wp-admin except if the call is made from let say /secretlogin. And you let /secretlogin redirect to wp-admin. Will this work?
If yes, how do I manage this with htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://www\.your_domain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-admin [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-login\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /homepage.htm [R=302,L]
```

Finally I used your method is easier to add.
You need to use a link from your /secretlogin page.

Comment: Hi Croises, this works as well, thanks. Only, when going to domain.com/wp-admin, it end in an redirect loop instead of an 404. Can I just redirect it to the homepage? And How do I 'block' domain.com/wp-login.php as well? Sorry bit noobish with complex htaccess.

Comment: I just add that to my answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! I blocked the secret login page for search engines, and nobody will ever know of it's existence. Definitely works as an extra security. :)

Comment: You can even protect this page with a password ;-)

Comment: True! Even better ;-) Thanks for your help! Just to be sure, it has to be an actual page from /secretlogin right, just an redirect from /secretlogin didn't work I suppose? (I saw it in previous edits)

Comment: That can be a link from any other page of the site. There is a problem with redirects is that the browser does not keep the intermediate page. You can redirect (php or JavaScript) in the /secretlogin page. Personally for this stuff (as I am also a little paranoid ;-). I add a cookie, and I tested it on the protected page. It's hard with WP.

Comment: For some reason, this script doesn't work when the secretlogin page is an .php page, not sure why? No big deal, but maybe its an easy fix?

Comment: If you don't change the referer in the page or in PHP configuration, that can't be the problem. Because you just test the referer domain.

Comment: Sorry forget about it, it was another htaccess thing that caused this issue, never mind. :) Works great now.